# How to get a echoed input field value using Php

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

How can i get the echoed input value using `$_post method`? I already tried `$_POST['prody'];` to get the echoed input field value but it don't work.

```
Employees Prize Name:&nbsp;<input class="form-control" type="text" id="prody" name="prody" required value="'.$prize.'" disabled></input>
```

`//$prize = $row['price_name']` `$prize` is a variable that i declared in a while loop and stored a value of price name.

Here is the example of the picture, the employee price name should not be clickable because its data is from the database the prize name is the only one that can be clickable.

[image]

Comment: If it's disabled, it doesn't get submitted.

Comment: Paste your full form code

Comment: Thanks @miken that worked! But is there any other way to make a input tag unclickable?

Comment: You can make it `readonly`, but an `<input>` is, by definition, designed to accept input.

Comment: what about a hidden input type?, but make sure its not going to be a problem if its edited, because any one could edit the value before it reaches your php

Comment: @IdontDownVote it needs to be shown for some purpose. ill add some photo

Comment: you could echo it as html (or as you have already)and still parse it as a hidden form element

Comment: It really can't be hidden it needs to be seen by the user but in a disabled state. Any other suggestions for a disabled input tag with submittable value? But thanks anywayss

Comment: i said "and" the two are not mutually exclusive

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've accomplished a similar task.

```
echo'<div class="form-group">
  <input id="lastedited" name="lastedited" type="text" value="Value Goes Here" class="form-control input-md" readonly>

  </div>
</div>';
```

I set the input as read only. Then on `$_POST` I can still `$_GET` the data I need and assign to a variable or manipulate as needed. You'll need to remember to query your database and assign it to a variable, this way you can include that in the form inputs value for when it gets submitted.